# PHP - Image Upload , move_uploaded_file not working?

Tags: php, redirect, image-uploading

I have coded a image upload script but when I click upload i get redirected to the upload page?

Here is the code:

```
    $image1name = $_FILES['image1']['name'];
    $image1crntloc = $_FILES['image1']['tmp_name'];
    $image1ext = pathinfo($image1name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $image1size = $_FILES['image1']['size'];

    $allowedext = array("jpg","gif","png");
    //check image 1 extension.
    if (!in_array($image1ext,$allowedext))
    {
        echo "<script>alert(\"Image 1 has an invalid file.\");</script>";
    }

    else{
        $image1final = md5(time($image1name));
        $saveimage1 = "../images/".$image1final.".".$image1ext;
        $image1uploadresult = move_uploaded_file($image1crntloc,       $saveimage1); 

        if ($image1uploadresult == TRUE)
        {
            echo "uploaded.";
        }
        else{
            echo "image not uploaded.";
        }
```

as soon as i click upload, i get redirected to the page where the user selects the image ,i have also checked the directory and nothing gets uploaded?
There is no PHP error shown as well.

Any help?

Thanks.

CODE FOR FORM:

```
<form id="new-ad" name="new-ad" method="post" action="includes/create.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="form-group animated fadeIn">
<label class="labelcustom" for "image1">Image #1:</label>
<br />
Select image to upload:
<input type="file" class="form-control" name="image1" id="image1" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: What does your `form` looks like?

Comment: i have added the code for the form.

Comment: Do you ever get the message `uploaded` or `image not uplaoded`?

Comment: nope , thats the problem . it just redirects me back to the form where the user uploads the image , and that redirected page  doesnt even load the CSS.

Comment: It looks like you are missing a `}` at the end of the last `else` statement.

Comment: oh i missed out the } when i was adding the code , sorry :( , the } is already included so thats not the problem i think.

Comment: UPDATE: you were right :) it was the } haha , thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are missing the closing bracket on your `else` statement:

```
else {
    echo "image not uploaded.";
}
```

Should be:

```
    else {
        echo "image not uploaded.";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your form, you forgot the max file size. Add `<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2097152" />` to it, were value is the max size in bytes to accept in the form.

Comment: ok the image uploads fine now but it still redirects me to the index page but it shouldnt ... ive added a header. Also the index page doesnt load any CSS and the url is still the same as the url of the page where the upload script is?

Comment: @Haris Mahmood does you php code include an `header` with the url or location attributes?